# Get the last element in list with helper

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am passing a list to my scala page and I have a form and I would like to set some default values to the last element in the list: Something like the below:

```
System Name: <input type="text" id="systemSourceName" name="systemSourceName" value="@configs[@configs.size() - 1].systemSourceName" >
```

But it throws an error at the second @:

```
identifier expected but '@' found.
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use round brackets, square brackets are for type parameters
2. There is no need for second `@`, parser knows that he is already inside scala expression.

It is better to use built-in method of [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) class:

```
value="@configs.last.systemSourceName"
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala doesn't access list elements via list[index] but via list(index).
So the following should work:

```
value="@configs(configs.size - 1).systemSourceName"
```

An easier solution would be

```
value="@configs.last.systemSourceName"
```